# Como deshabilitar un option en un select

Tags: javascript, php

Estoy trabajando con **PHP** y **JavaScript**.

Tengo un `select`, el cual se llena al traer los datos desde una **BD**.
Lo que intento hacer es que al seleccionar una opción del `select`, se deshabilite para que el usuario no pueda acceder de nuevo a esa opción.
Alguien me puede echar una mano?´

Aquí dejo un poco de mi código:

```html
<select id="Cursos">  </center>
  <option id="opt0" value="#">Seleccione su curso</option>
  <?php 
   
   while($curso=pg_fetch_array($resultado)){
  ?>
  <option id="opt1" value="<?php echo $curso[id_curso] ?>"><?php echo $curso[1] ?> </option> <?php } ?> 
 </select> 
 <input type="submit" name="btn1" onclick="quest00.php" value="Ir al curso">
 <script> </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que quieres que ocurra es que se deshabilite la `select` completa para que el usuario no pueda cambiar su selección, lo que puedes hacer es cambiar añadir el atributo `disabled` con el valor `disabled` o `true`.

Debes tener en cuenta que **los campos que están deshabilitados no se envían con el formulario**, por lo que deberías añadir un campo oculto con el mismo `name` que el select y el valor que se seleccionó (y ese sí se enviará sin problemas).

Aquí puedes ver un ejemplo funcionando:

```js
document.getElementById("Cursos").addEventListener("change", function() {

  // crea un campo oculto con el mismo nombre que la lista desplegable
  var oculto = document.createElement("input");
  oculto.type  = "hidden";
  oculto.value = this.value;
  oculto.name  = this.name;
  document.getElementById("miForm").appendChild(oculto);
  
  // deshabilita la lista desplegable
  this.disabled = "disabled";
});
```

```html
<form id="miForm">
  <select id="Cursos" name="Cursos">  
    <option id="opt0" value="#">Seleccione su curso</option>
    <option id="opt1" value="1">Curso 1</option>
    <option id="opt2" value="2">Curso 2</option>
    <option id="opt3" value="3">Curso 3</option>
  </select> 
  <input type="submit" name="btn1" value="Ir al curso">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

A la opción que quieras deshabilitar agregale la propiedad `disabled` pero lo que realmente necesitas es una condición para que cuando se cumpla entonces imprima esta propiedad. Considera el siguiente código:

```
while($curso=pg_fetch_array($resultado)){   
    echo '<option id="opt1" value="'. $curso[id_curso] .'" ' . ($se_deshabilita == true ? 'disabled' : '') . '>' . $curso[1] .'</option>';
} 
?>  
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta jamás quitarle el poder de decisión a un usuario, provee una mala experiencia de usuario (UX, valga la redundancia).

```js
function onChange (select) {
  const value = select.value;
  let option = select.querySelector(`option[value="${value}"]`);
  option.disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<select onchange="onChange(this)">
  <option value="a">A</option>
  <option value="b">B</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Ojo con esta solución porque puede conllevar problemas: cuando se envían los formularios, los campos que están `disabled` son ignorados. Así que si el usuario cambia el valor por defecto de la `select`, al deshabilitarse el `option`, es como si el `select` estuviera deshabilitado y no se enviará con el formulario. Aquí puedes ver [un ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/weoc98af/) de lo que digo. Prueba a enviar el formulario, mira el log, cambia la `select`, vuelve a enviar el formulario y verás en el log que no se manda lo mismo.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, además de problemas lógicos también existen problemas de usabilidad. Yo no veo la necesidad de desactivar una opción en el caso del OP, porque si luego cambia de opinión ya no podrá volver a la selección anterior. En fin, es una mala idea. Gracias por tu comentario.

Answer (score 0):

Una alternativa es usar el plugin Chosen o select2, que ademas de la funcionalidad que necesitas aporta otras caracteristicas.

Chosen: https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Select 2 https://select2.github.io/examples.html